# Zend Validate PostCode in a Zend Form -> Validate depending on given country

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, validation

How can I validate a zipcode field in my form depending on the country set in the "country" field in the same form?

I somehow need to get access to the form instance or the value of another field. Is there a way to do this in a Callback validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "Validation Context" note on this page - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html (no direct link, just Ctrl+F `Validation Context`)

You can use the `$context` in a custom validator to access the rest of the submitted form data.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by adding a new class that does the PostCode check. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/971363